# Adding html and js code under React src folder

Tags: reactjs

I have folder(say `SDK`) inside my React public folder containing a bunch of html and js/jQuery files.

I'm accessing these files inside my react code as a iframe with src http://example.com/SDK/homepage.html.

How can I move this SDK folder from public/SDK to src/SDK in the React project and then access homepage.html in the iframe in my React code?

I've bootstrapped the app with Create React App and using `yarn build` to build it.

Comment: You have missed entire point of React if you are going to use jQuery and/or iframe

Comment: I'm trying to include a separate module that was developed independently in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Well, the official way is exactly like you are doing it: put it into the public folder (see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

If you, for what ever reason, still want to put it in `src`, then you would need your build tool to copy the files during build time.

If you use **Webpack** then you could use the copy plug in https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin

When you are using **create-react-app** and you do not want to eject (so you could use the webpack solution), then you could also write a small script within your `package.yml` to copy the files into the `build` folder. This - however - is not so great to maintain and will not scale.

```
{
  "name": "some-project",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "cp './src/SDK' './public/SDK' && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
}
```

This is the relevant part: `"build": "cp './src/SDK' './public/SDK' && react-scripts build",`

Comment: I'm using create react app so I might have to do a eject to change the config files. Does this allow me to access http://example.com/SDK/homepage.html and have my homepage.html inside src/SDK folder and not public/SDK ?

Comment: yes you would need to eject if you want to configure the webpack copy plugin. I added more info to the answer and how you maybe can do it dfferently.